# Chaining an input option after a select?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm wondering how I can chain an input box after chaining a selection in my form.

I'm using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained to chain my selects and it works. However, I need to adjust this to also allow for the chaining of an input. In the below example it would be someone would choose an option such has an item has Strength on it then the select menu of value options then input the value. I'm trying to also incorporate into this where after those 3 options of item, controller, value are inputed the user has the option to filter more so another box appear with the same options of strength, agility, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XMx4Q/ is an example of work I used to incorporate this into my own work.

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <div>
        <label for="searchterm">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="searchterm">
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="chainedSelectFilter">
            <select name="specificFilter" class="attribute">
                <option value="" selected>Select a Filter</option>
                <option value="strength">Has Strength</option>
                <option value="agility">Has Agility</option>
                <option value="spirit">Has Spirit</option>
                <option value="stamina">Has Stamina</option>
            </select>
                <select name="specificFilter" class="valueController">
                    <option value=">" selected>></option>
                    <option value=">=">>=</option>
                    <option value="=">=</option>
                    <option value="<=">&#60;=</option>
                    <option value="<">&#60;</option>
                </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
    <label for="submit"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/XMx4Q/3/

Comment: Here is another approach http://jsfiddle.net/XMx4Q/6/

Comment: Yes that second one is what I was going for Dave. Chaining a select + an input off of some of my initial selects while others have a different set up. My first select can have something like <has strength> <=> [5] for example then another one may be <has socket> <yes> and thats the end of that.

Comment: So does the second one solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code reference below shows how to accomplish this. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMx4Q/6/) that shows it's working.

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
    <div class="container">
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="chain" value="" placeholder="Type here"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="chain" value="" placeholder="type here"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="text" class="chain" value=""/> 
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('select').change(function () { 
    $(this).next('input').fadeIn();
});
$('body').on('keyup','input.chain',function () {    
    $(this).parent().next('div').fadeIn();
});
```